# AppleScript - Fill in Outlook Subject via Keystroke Simulation

Tags: outlook, applescript, automator, keystroke

I am searching for an AppleScript which is able to simulate Key strokes in the below mentioned Script. The keystrokes should fill the "subject" and "content" field.

Please note: Unfortunately it is not enough to just fill in a complete strings since I need the keystrokes to activate an "Alfred-Text snipped" (Auto expansion function for text snippets).

I have already found some possibilities in the net like the example below but I'm not sure how this can be combinded with my script since "Subject" is expecting a string, and not keystrokes.

Is there an API for AppleScript in Outlook to insert keystrokes? Or is there another viable solution for this?

```
-- Keystroke example
tell application "System Events"       
    key code 124 using {shift down, command down}
end tell




on run {input, parameters}
    set SelectedItems to input

    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message
        tell newMessage
            repeat with aFile in SelectedItems
                make new cc recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:"Business Support", address:"business_suppport@xxxx"}}
                make new attachment with properties {file:aFile}

                set subject to "XXXXXXXX"
                set content to "XXXXXXXX"
            end repeat
        end tell
        open newMessage
        get newMessage
        activate
    end tell
```

Comment: If you wish a certain combination of keystrokes to trigger a text expansion from _Alfred_, could you instead insert the expanded version of the text in the first instance and thus negate the need for _Alfred_ to do it ?

Comment: @CJK Hey CJK. Thanks a lot for the hint. Unfortunately the Alfred script does contain placeholders which get expandet when the snippet is used. So just to copy the snippet text into the script wouldn't be enough.

Comment: You misunderstood I think.  I am not suggesting to insert the snippet text, i.e. the pre-expanded text. I’m saying you should insert the fully-expanded text from within the AppleScript.  _Alfred_ won’t need to expand the text then, as it will already be expanded.

Comment: Hey @CJK. I've already tested both, filling in the short name of the snipped and also the text that will be expanded after using the snipped. But the text of the snipped does contain placehoders that will be expanded by Alfred by using the short name of the snipped. 


For example: 
• short name of the snipped "flb"
• Text in Alfred not expanded for the snipped "flb": "Report {date -1M:MMMM} 2019 - Projekt N° {clipboard:0}"
• Final expanded subject in the mail: "Report November 2019 - Projekt N° B1900685"

Comment: But all of that can be handled by the AppleScript...that's my point.  You already know what `"flb"` should expand to; and, in turn, it's easy to deal with `{date - 1M:MMMM}` and `{clipboard:0}` in AppleScript, or don't forget you can also create an _Alfred_ workflow specifically to serve as a worker-bee for your AppleScript (which can call _Alfred_ workflows and pass parameters to and from etc.). Let me explain why I'm pushing this: keystroking is a poor, unreliable method, it **will** break, and it will fail to trigger an _Alfred_ expansion if keystrokes at too fast or too slow. _Con'td..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ On the other hand, Outlook has a dedicated, robust means of setting a subject of an email with AppleScript.  And AppleScript has a dedicated, robust means of interacting with _Alfred_ cooperatively (`run trigger...in workflow...with argument...`) versus keystrokes that force AppleScript and _Alfred_ to work independently, unaware of one another, and with no say over how or what the other does and when.  So you can achieve exactly what you want, even with text expansions, by using a workflow.  Or you can just use AppleScript and I can show you how to parse the `{...}` bits.